# ¿Cómo puedo leer carácter por carácter de una serie de letras juntas y sin vectores?

Tags: c++

Me gustaría poder diferenciar diferentes caracteres de una sola frase y todo junto, pero no lo consigo. Hasta ahora lo que he intentado es esto pero no funciona obviamente:

```
    char cadena;

    cout << "Introduce la secuencia: ";

    while(cin && check == false){
        cin >> cadena;

        if(cadena == 'l'){
            nEles++;        
        }

        check = true; //Cuando termina de leer termina el bucle
    }

    cout << nEles << endl;
```

Me gustaría introducir como entrada algo como:
lollooolollo

Y poder diferenciar carácter por carácter sin usar vectores, he probado también con funciones string pero me ha resultado más complicado y no se me ocurre otra forma. Gracias.

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con diferenciar carácteres?

Comment: @Chariot poder leer letra por letra con la capacidad de poder diferenciar una de otra cuando el usuario introduzca en una única línea una serie de letras juntas.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes leer carácter a carácter utilizando la clase string de la stl:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string cadena;
    char caracter;
    cout << "introduce la secuencia: ";

    cin >> cadena;
    int longitud = cadena.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < longitud; i++) {
        caracter = cadena[i];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Mientras vaya avanzando el bucle se va leyendo cada uno de los carácteres del string y se almacena en la variable char caracter.
pd:
"sin usar vectores": no entiendo porque no usar vectores, no se me ocurre de otra forma.

Comment: ¿Sería posible hacer que me lea toda la cadena de char sin usar vectores? He pensado en usar un bucle while(cin >> cadena) pero no encuentro una forma de solucionarlo así. Gracias por tu aportación.

Comment: @GuillermoSantamaría no veo la forma, para leer cadenas necesitas utilizar vectores, ya que debes recorrer la cadena. ¿Pero para que necesitas que no se usen vectores?

Comment: porque es un ejercicio que necesito resolver sin el uso de vectores. Alguna solución debe de haber, yo he pensado en coger caracter por caracter con un bucle en una sola línea e ir incluyendo las condiciones dentro del bucle para ir diferenciando caracter por caracter.

Answer (score 0):

> he probado también con funciones string pero me ha resultado más complicado

Te prometo que yo no lo veo tan complicado como dices:

```
#include <string>

std::string cecuencia;
std::cin >> secuencia;

if( secuencia == "lollooolollo" )
{
  // ...
}
```

Comment: La idea es leer caracter por caracter y diferenciar uno de otro con condiciones a parte, lo que tú me has mostrado es como comparar un string con otro string.

Comment: @GuillermoSantamaría lo que tu pretendes es, en resumidas cuentas, eso mismo. Porqué no pruebas a contarnos tu idea con más detalle a ver qué pasa?

Comment: Sí, llevas razón debería explicarlo con mayor detalle. Lo que yo pretendo es leer una secuencia de caracteres en una misma línea sin espacios y poder analizar (usar condiciones) con cada uno de los caracteres de esa secuencia sin usar vectores.